# Por que criaram o Raw Literals em C#?

Tags: c#, string, sintaxe, estilo-de-codificação

No C# 11 foi introduzido um novo recurso chamado "Raw String Literal", que na prática permite criar strings múltiplas linhas, mas não entendi muito bem seu propósito.

Na documentação, aparentemente posso criar strings em múltiplas linhas no código, mas isso já era possível com "Verbatim Strings".

```
string name = "world";

 // antes do C# 11
string beforeCs11 = $@"
    Hello,
    {name}!
";

 // depois do C# 11
string afterCs11 = $"""
    Hello,
    {name}!
""";
```

Aparentemente ambos produzem resultados semelhantes, mas não vi uso real do que foi lançado recentemente.

Qual a diferença entre eles? Por que criaram o último? Existe diferença no IL para cada um destes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nova forma é mais poderosa e flexível. Alguns pontos podem ser alcançados agora que antes não. A forma nova é especialmente útil quando você está colando um texto no código que tem partes que poderiam ser interpretadas de forma equivocada (quando cola formatos tais como XML, JSON, HTML, ou até mesmo SQL e outros códigos). Vou dar alguns exemplos mostrando a diferença, começando quando não há diferença:

```
using static System.Console;

var name = "world";
WriteLine($"""
    Hello,
    {name}!
""");

WriteLine($@"
    Hello,
    {name}!
");
```

Mas agora vamos ver um caso que não funciona com *string verbatim*, onde você está postando um texto que tem aspas ou mesmo digitando um que deve tê-las:

```
WriteLine($"""
    "Hello,
    {name}!"
""");

WriteLine(@$"
    "Hello,
    {name}!"
");
```

Obviamente que você poderia usar a *string* normal que pode escapar esses caracteres que podem causar problema, mas dá um trabalho enorme (este é um exemplo pequeno, imagine um texto gigante) e fica feio e propenso a erros. Em alguns casos pode ser problema porque se não usar o *verbatim* complica com os caracteres que fazem parte do código mas não do texto, como pular linha.

E tem mais uma coisa interessante que é poder usar aspas duplicadas sem problemas:

```
WriteLine($"""
    ""Hello,
    {name}!""
""");
```

Mas espere, tem mais!

Pode até usar usar aspas repetidas mais vezes. Só que aí terá que aumentar a quantidade do delimitador para indicar para o compilador que o que está no meio do texto é só texto. Portanto, para tirar a ambiguidade, se tiver aspas em triplicata dentro do texto, o início e fim da *string* toda deve ter pelo menos 4 aspas:

```
WriteLine($""""
    """Hello,
    {name}!"""
    \t
"""");
```

Note que aproveitei para mostrar que não é escapado caracteres especiais.

Ainda não acabou.

É possível fazer a interpolação ter algo parecido. Se precisar interpretar as chaves como texto, é possível fazer isso repetindo o `$`, assim está indiciando que a interpolação só ocorrerá com a quantidade de chaves igual a quantidade de cifrões usados na declaração do literal:

```
WriteLine($$"""
    Hello,
    {name}!
    Hello,
    {{name}}!
    """);

WriteLine(@$"
    Hello,
    {name}!
    Hello,
    {{name}}!
    ");
```

Viu que dá um resultado diferente do *verbatim* normal? Veja no *link* lá embaixo como fica.

E viu que aproveitei para mostrar outro detalhe? Quando você indenta o fechamento igual ao texto, a indentação dele não é considerada parte do texto e é ignorada. No jeito antigo a indentação continua sendo considerada parte do texto. Isso é algo que pode ajudar muito você organizar seu código sem estragar o texto, antes o código ficava feio para não incluir a indentação.

Você pode achar estranho ter que usar 3 aspas. É por uma questão de ambiguidade. Com apenas 2 delas pode confundir com uma *string* vazia, daria erro:

```
WriteLine($""
    Hello,
    {name}!
"");
```

Ou mesmo confundir com uma abertura e fechamento:

```
WriteLine(@$"
    "Hello,
    {name}!"
");
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JSm0Ua). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/RawStringLiteral.cs).

A mudança do IL depende. Eles não produzem o mesmo resultado, então o IL é diferente de alguma forma, mas nada mudou além da superfície, ou seja, não precisa nada especial no IL, não depende de instruções diferentes, é só como a *string* será armazenada nele, e é só a forma do compilador interpretar.

Comment: Isso acaba sendo extremamente útil para incorporar textos JSON, XML etc...

Comment: Sim, totalmente.